# Refreshing "online" users with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a chat app where it shows users who are online (username + profile pic). I have an ajax poll that basically checks to see which users are still online, and refreshes the list automatically. Also, the list is ordered based on last activity.

The way I've been doing it is:

1. Get list of current online users
2. Clear existing elements
3. Re-add them (will be ordered correctly since the returned list from step1 is ordered)

This works fine in Chrome, but I notice in Firefox that it is causing a "flickering" effect while the images get re-added.

What is the best way to do this? It seems overly difficult to create an algorithm check which elements exist, if they are in the right order and move them, etc. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried doing it such that you keep the old DOM elements but update the text & `<img>` "src" attributes?  Then you just need to add new ones when the active count goes up, and remove old ones only when there are spares.

Comment: But then I have to create an algorithm to find out which ones need to be removed, reordered, or added. This can get quite difficult to keep track of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How often do you poll to see if users are still online?

I think the best way may be to give the user records unique ids so you can then check the list of users that were online against the new list of users that are now online.

fade away the users that have left and fade in any that have logged on.

It will be a much more elegant solution and it solves the problem you are having.

Comment: How would you go about doing the reordering? (The users are ordered by lastActivity, i.e: the last time they messaged you). You then iterate over both lists to get rid of the ones that should be removed or added. Then iterate over the list again to correct the order.

Comment: I would amend the order as the action that means the order should change occurs.  - what I mean by this is when someone messages you move them to the top or bottom of the list (however you order your users). This way the users should be in the correct order the whole time. If that doesn't make sense please say and I will try and explain again :)

Comment: I think I understand, but could you reitarate just to be sure? The problem is, the API call that I have available simply returns me the list of users (in the right order). So there is no way for me to find out (other then comparing the lists) what has changed.

Comment: OK as you are restricted by an API you have to do it slightly differently.. but you can still do pretty much the same thing. You need to maintain user order in your app between polls. the list you get back from the server will have users in the same order as your member list, just we some removed and maybe some added. its simple to remove the people that are no longer online from your list.. just fade them out.. as for adding the people that have just logged on, this could be harder. You said before that people are ordered according to their communications with you...

Comment: so the people that have just logged on have no communications so would just get put at the end of the list..??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would try to "cache" the images separately, using the "preload" technique. That's when you create an `Image` object and set it's `src` to the URL of the userpic. Then you store all those objects in a global array. This will prevent the browser from getting rid of the images when they are no longer on the screen, so that it will not have to load them again when you reload the list.

If that doesn't help, I would actually reuse the existing list elements. I would just go over the elements, one by one, and replace their content with the appropriate content from the list. If I run out of existing elements in the process, I add new ones. If any elements are left over when the list ends, I remove them. This is a bit more complex, but actually not as complex as it looks at first glance.

Comment: I am going to try preloading/caching the images. If this gets rid of the flickering issue in FF, I might just KISS and stick with removing everything and readding.